# Server closed the connection unexpectedly. This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I've been trying to import a .sql file from a local directory into my PostgreSQL database ("bikeshare"). I'm currently using Linux OS (Ubuntu)

I made the recommended adjustments to both files listed below:

1. `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf` (tried listen_address = "*" and "::")
2. `/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf` (local all postgres md5)

I've also tried allowing access to all databases for all users with an encrypted password. (`host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`)

Every time I try this (after changing into a directory with the .sql file):

```
$ psql -U Postgres -d bike-share -f status.sql
```

I get this error message:

```
psql:/home/glenn/Documents/PostgreSQL/status.sql:27612953: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
psql:/home/glenn/Documents/PostgreSQL/status.sql:27612953: connection to server was lost
```

I've also tried doing this:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# \c bikeshare
postgres=# \i '/home/glenn/Documents/PostgreSQL/status.sql'
```

And this:

```
$ psql -h Glenn -d bikeshare -U postgres -f status.sql
```

And every time I get the same error above.

Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Changes to `pg_hba.conf` or `listen_address` won't help with that error as those control the _initial_ connection which clearly works. You need to consult the Postgres log file if that contains any information why the connection was killed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  

found that it was a memory issue. I was able to upload other smaller SQL files (6 kB to 45 MB), but the file that is causing me trouble is about 1 GB. I tried modifying the `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf` **work_mem** and other parameters, but still getting the same error. What's the next step?